# Property that a pdf is equal to 1 between limits $-\infty$ and $\infty$

Tags: statistics

Suppose that a random variable $Y$ has a probability density function given by

f(y) =
\begin{cases}
ky^3e^{-\frac{y}{2}},  &  y>0 \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}

(a) Find the value of $k$ that makes $f(y($ a density function.

(b) Does $Y$ have a chi-square distribution? If so, how many degrees of freedom?

(c) What are the mean and standard deviation of $Y$?

---

Solution

(a) $\int ^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(y)$ $dy=1$

$=\int^{\infty}_0 y^3e^{-\frac{y}{2}}$ $dy=\frac{1}{k}$

I obtained

$e^{-\frac{y}{2}}[-2y^3-12y^2-48y-6]^{\infty}_0=\frac{1}{k}$

What happens when $y$ tends to $\infty$?

Foe (b), I do not know.

For (c), I will be able to manage if my part (a) is explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $n$, $\lim\limits_{y\to\infty}e^{-y/2}y^n = 0$

The pdf of a [Chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) of $\kappa$ degrees of freedom is : $$f_Y(y)~=~\dfrac{y^{\kappa/2-1}e^{-y/2}}{2^{\kappa/2}\Gamma(\kappa/2)}$$